# Annoying red triangle with an exclamation mark in system tray

Tags: repository, system-tray

I had a read through some similar topics to this problem but none of them actually figured out how to solve this. The topics are still open without "niked" answers.

Does anyone know what can I do given that I'm using mirror for the UK (I tried different ones too), system says it's up to date and when I run 'apt-get update / upgrade' nothing really changes. No error messages. Simply nothing. Nada.

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you sure the red triangle is for updates? If you hover over is there a message?

Comment: When I click on the exclamation mark it shows:  "The information update is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by selecting 'show updates' and watch for failing repositories".

Comment: When I do that I get "Your system is up to date".

Comment: It could be a repository that is offline or has an expired key. When you run `sudo apt update` what messages do you get other than `Hit ...`, `Get...` or `Ign ...`?

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release --codename&&uname --kernel-release`?

Comment: Other than that it reads just "Fetched 204 kB in 0s (341 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done"

Comment: 'Codename: xenial
4.8.0-54-generic'